Auto login to Microsoft Office 365 products
We have several Windows 11 Azure VMs and multiple users in Azure AD with an Office 365 license.
Currently, when a new user logs into a VM for the first time, they must provide credentials to log into Office products. Once logged in, their credentials are retained for future sessions.
When a user logs into a VM, we need Microsoft Office applications such as Excel and Word to  automatically log in, without specifying credentials.
We want to streamline this process so that Office products automatically log in during the first login to the VM.
